# Find duplicates within group in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Say I have a spreadsheet with the following:

```
RoadIDs | Order
   0        0
   0        0
   0        0
   0        0
   0        0
   0        0
   0        1
   0        2
   1        1
```

I'd want to be able to show that `RoadID` `0` has 6 duplicates (i.e. `0` shows up in the `Order` column 6 times.

The final output would be:

```
RoadIDs | Duplicates
   0          6
   1          0
```

I tried `=COUNTIF(A:A,A2)` but this just gave me the counts for the RoadID.

Comment: =COUNTIF under your Duplicates column, referencing your RoadIDs column

Comment: @EricF That just gives me the counts of my `RoadIDs`, I'd like to see how many times `Order` `0` shows up in `RoadID` `0`.

Comment: try `=COUNTIFS` (that extra "s" makes a huge difference)

Comment: how many times `Order 0` shows up in `RoadID 0` -> 6 || how many times `Order 1` shows up in `RoadID 0` -> 1 || how many times `Order 2` shows up in `RoadID 0` -> 1 || how many times `Order 1` shows up in `RoadID 1` -> 1 ........ is these the count you expect to get?